# downgrade Google Apps from business to free edition

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I did it before but now i can't find the downgrade link, There was a link to downgrade to the standard free edition if the users are less than 10.

Is there anyway to downgrade or to subscribe directly for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2855120),

unfortunately, As of December 6, 2012, Google no longer offers new accounts for the free edition of Google Apps. Google Apps free edition is sometimes referred to as "Standard Edition." If you already have the free edition, you can continue to use it for free. This change has no impact on existing users of the free edition.

Answer (score 0):

From December 6, 2012 Google has close their Apps for free - Standard edition. But till you can avail on your domain for FREE for Lifetime. You need to add your domain to a Google Apps for free edition.

I have some domains enabled with Google Apps for Free. I want to sell those domains.